# How to use async and await in Extjs Extended Class methods constructor, initcomponent

Tags: extjs, extjs7-classic

```
 initComponent: async function () {
        var me = this;
        const isPivotLoaded = Ext.Package.isLoaded('ckeditor');
        if (!isPivotLoaded) {
            var result = await Ext.Package.load('ckeditor').catch(function(error){console.log(error)});
            if (!result) {
                alert('Error loading package!');
                return;
            }
        }
```

Here i used package to download external files, but it wont wait until file downloaded, how to achieve it in extjs

Comment: I would not recommend using async function in `initComponent`. Try to display a loading mask, start an Ajax request or use a Promise, remove the mask when it is completed and do what you need to do after the async function.